# What's relationship between C language and von neumann architecture?

Tags: c, assembly, architecture

I ever heard someone say that "because von neumann architecture is ubiquitous, C language will never disappear."
I don't know what does he mean. 
Are there some special relationship between C language and von neumann architecture?

### Thanks!

I find a paper that discuss c and von neumann in this [pdf file](http://konstantin.solnushkin.org/teaching_reports/intro_to_hpc/2007/harvard_architecture.pdf) .
It makes my question more specific.(page 2-6)

Comment: C is not going to disappear any time in the foreseeable future, but that's not because of any special relationship with the von Neumann architecture.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thats opinion based I guess. Too many things are written in C and changing now would be costly I guess. Or could you elaborate please ?

Comment: Nothing at all. C admits Harvard architecture implementations just as well.

Comment: @TonyTannous, naturally any prediction of the future has to fall on the "opinion" side of the fact *vs*. opinion scale.  Nevertheless, my analysis is based not only on the momentum factors you describe, but also on the fact that C is simply a very good fit to some problem domains (which indeed has fed its momentum).  These days there are fewer problems than once there were for which C is the first-choice language, but plenty such problems remain.

Answer (score 3):

The von Neumann model essentially has a computer architecture that consists of a processor that executes instructions sequentually, memory, I/O devices, and a bus between them.

Human beings tend to be better at reasoning about sequential processes than about parallel or other non-sequential processes.   The purpose of a programming language is to allow people to communicate instructions to a machine, so a lot of programming languages - including C - either assume or support thinking about a computer as if it has a von-neuman architecture (a single CPU system) or an architecture in which multiple sequential processors are strung together (either sequentially or in parallel).

However, there is no specific linkage between the von Neumann model and modern programming languages.   Programming in C (or most other languages) is certainly easier if one can assume a von Neumann architecture, which is why modern hardware - even if it has more complex architecture - often seeks to behave as if it is structured that way.     Modern languages - including C - either support, or are evolving to support, different system architectures.

However, the von Neumann architecture is not the reason that C remains popular or ubiquitous.    There are many factors contributing to that.

Comment: I deleted my prior comments because they didn't seem to be contributing much to the original question relating C and von Neumann architecture, versus von Neumann architectures that include parallel / vector operation, and I don't see why C can't be used on a Harvard architecture such as some DSPs.

Answer (score -1):

Well, there is a relationship between C language and the Von Neumann Architecture. The language C is based on the programming style of the von Neumann computer. Fortran and Java is based on Von Neumann. You can find more information on this [link.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_programming_languages) Also, the reason they Von Neumann Architecture is ubiquitous because of the languages based on it. Java and C are everywhere around the world.

Comment: The Wikipedia article you're linking to is one of the worst I have seen for quite some time. C, for example, doesn't have an affiliation to VNM - It works just as well on a Harvard architecture - Proven by something as tiny as an AVR C compiler.

Comment: hello, tofro. You can refer this pdf document. http://konstantin.solnushkin.org/teaching_reports/intro_to_hpc/2007/harvard_architecture.pdf